# How to display optimal variable values of a class-type Pyomo model?

Tags: gurobi, pyomo

I am a new Pyomo/Python user, and I am just wondering how to display the optimal variable values in a class-type Pyomo model.

I have just tried the standard example from Pyomo example library, the "min-cost-flow model". The code is available in https://github.com/Pyomo/PyomoGallery/wiki/Min-cost-flow

At the bottom of the code, it says:

```
sp = MinCostFlow('nodes.csv', 'arcs.csv') 
sp.solve()
print('\n\n---------------------------')
print('Cost: ', sp.m.OBJ())
```

and the output is

```
Academic license - for non-commercial use only
Read LP format model from file.    
Reading time = 0.00 seconds
x8: 7 rows, 8 columns, 16 nonzeros
No parameters matching 'mip_tolerances_integrality' found
No parameters matching 'mip_tolerances_mipgap' found
Optimize a model with 7 rows, 8 columns and 16 nonzeros
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Objective range  [1e+00, 5e+00]
  Bounds range     [0e+00, 0e+00]
  RHS range        [1e+00, 1e+00]
Presolve removed 7 rows and 8 columns
Presolve time: 0.00s
Presolve: All rows and columns removed
Iteration    Objective       Primal Inf.    Dual Inf.      Time
       0    5.0000000e+00   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00      0s

Solved in 0 iterations and 0.01 seconds
Optimal objective  5.000000000e+00
```

I can only get the optimal objective, but how about the optimal variable values? I have also searched the documentation, which told me to use something like:

```
print("x[2]=",pyo.value(model.x[2])).
```

But it did not work for class-type models like the min-cost-flow model.

I also tried to modify the function definition in the class:

```
def solve(self):
        """Solve the model."""
        solver = pyomo.opt.SolverFactory('gurobi')
        results = solver.solve(self.m, tee=True, keepfiles=False, options_string="mip_tolerances_integrality=1e-9, mip_tolerances_mipgap=0")
        print('\n\n---------------------------')
        print('First Variable: ', self.m.Y[0])
```

But it did not work as well. The output is:

```
KeyError: "Index '0' is not valid for indexed component 'Y'"
```

Can you help me with this? Thanks!

Gabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to display the model results after solution is to use the `model.display()` function. In your case, `self.m.display()`.

The `display()` function works on `Var` objects as well, so if you have a variable `self.m.x`, you could do `self.m.x.display()`.